# create jquery plugin by result function

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am trying to create a jQuery plugin.

```
$.fn.examplePlugin = function() {
    $.item = $(this);
    $(this).hide('fast',function () {
        return 'bla';
    });
}
```

I need to display the result in function :

```
$('form').examplePlugin(function(data)) {
    alert('data'); // need to return 'bla'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.fn.examplePlugin = function (callback) {
   $(this).hide('fast', function () { callback('bla'); });
}
$('form').examplePlugin(function (data) {
   alert(data);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u8tgA/

Note that there are better ways to write plugins .. look up [jQuery Plugin Boilerplate](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#jquerypluginpatterns).

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.examplePlugin = function() {
    $.item = $(this);
    $(this).hide('fast',function () {
        return 'bla';
    });

    function show(a) {
       alert(a);
    }    

}
```

need modify to:

```
$('form').examplePlugin(function(data)) {
    this.show('data'); // need to return alert 'bla'
});
```